# How to pass custom object arraylist from activity to fragment with instance

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-bundle

I am using viewpager and creating fragments and i want to pass the arraylist. So i have tried the below things:

MainActivity:

```
 private ArrayList<customers> mArrayList = null;

  ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager());

  adapter.addFrag(NewCustomer.newInstance(mArrayList ), "NewCustomer");
```

Now in fragment class i am creating instance:

```
 public static final ArrayList<customers> data = new ArrayList<customers>();

 public static final NewCustomer newInstance(ArrayList<customers> mArrayList) {

        NewCustomer f = new NewCustomer();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putParcelableArrayList(data, mArrayList);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }
```

But this is not working. It is showing error on bdl.putParcelableArrayList I want to get arraylist and store into the local arraylist of that class.

How can i get the arraylist with my custom object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try ?

```
public static final NewCustomer newInstance(ArrayList<customers> mArrayList) {

        NewCustomer f = new NewCustomer();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        this.data = mArrayList; // assign its Value
        bdl.putParcelableArrayList(data, mArrayList);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }
```

`this.data = mArrayList` will assign value to the current member variable of fragment. Now it can we be accessed in current fragment.

Comment: You should explain why the code you provide is working and what is it doing. If you provide simply a code, this won't help the OP and the following users that could end up with a similar question.

Comment: Don't apologize ;) But how are you explaining the usage of `this` in a static context ? I don't really get that part. Or the wrong usage of the method ;)

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter you are passing is wrong.
Check the definition:

```
putParcelableArrayList(String key, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)
```

Define the key as following in your fragment:

```
public static final String KEY;
```

To get the arraylist as local variable in your fragment use following code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    ArrayList<customers> customer_list = arguments.getParcelable(KEY);
}
```

Comment: That's well written. You could add the [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and also show how to call putParcelable with the KEY (that you need to initialize since this is a constant)

Answer (score 0):

please check that your model class "NewCustomer" implements Parcelable.